# Why will my XML be ordered by the names of the parameters from the XmlType-propOrder in JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

I am using BEA Workshop 10.3.0, I have a j2ee java class:

```
@XmlType(propOrder={"CORR_ID", "USER_NAME" , "APPLICATION"}) 
public class HeaderIn {

private String   CORR_ID;
private String   USER_NAME;
private String   APPLICATION;

public CmsfLoyAccHistDataTp() {
}

getters/setters()
}
```

and I will get this xml from:

```
<java:HEADER_IN>
 <java:APPLICATION>?</java:APPLICATION>
 <java:CORR_ID>?</java:CORR_ID>
 <java:USER_NAME>?</java:USER_NAME>
</java:HEADER_IN>
```

You can see, in the xml the parameters will be ordered by their name, and my sequence won't matter. The CORR_ID should be the first, the USER_NAME the 2nd, and the APPLICATION the last. Why is that? Please.. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Which version of java you are using?

Comment: Did you got the solution for your problem?